# r_basicprofile for V2 api

Tags: api, linkedin-api

According to the documents listed below r_basicprofile should be available for the V2 api. I have tested using both endpoints:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
and
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{my id})

and both of these return with an error message of

{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /***",
    "status": 403
}

If I use just the r_liteprofile permission, then I do get back the first name, last name and Id. as listed in the docs.

Has anyone else had success retrieving the basicprofile back from the V2 linkedin API.

According to the docs only the r_fullprofile permission needs special permission.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/full-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context

thanks

Comment: to answer my own question, Linkedin released this update today, which clearly states you will not have access to r_basicprofile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context